# Aligning Multiple Tables on Different Rows with Bootstrap

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 2 and having an issues getting tables to align.

I have a view in my Rails app where I want to show 4 tables - 2 tables per row (2 x 2), like this:

```
|   table   ||  table   |
|   table   ||  table   |
```

instead, I'm getting this:

```
|   table   ||  table   |
         |   table   |
|  table   |
```

The first two tables are aligned like I want, but the third table is not horizontally aligned correctly I can't figure out why.

```
# view
<div class="container">    
  <div class="row">
    <%= render :partial=>"article_count", :locals=>{:most_popular_articles=>@most_popular_articles}%>
  </div> 
</div>

# _article_count
<% @most_popular_articles.each do |article| %>
  <div class="span5">
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          # header names
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <% user.each do |user| %>
          <tr>
            # field values
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="span1"></div>
<% end %>
```

Here's a [link to the page](http://goo.gl/BqORxT) so you can see how it looks, as well as the full CSS and HTML rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try somthing like this:

```
<% @most_popular_articles.in_groups_of(2).each do |article_array|%>
    <div class="row">
        <% article_array.each do |article| %> 
            <div class="span5">
                <table class="table table-hover">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      # header names
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <% user.each do |user| %>
                      <tr>
                        # field values
                      </tr>
                    <% end %>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            <div class="span1"></div>
                <%end%>
        </div>
<%end%>
```